# Show git branches that diverged from remote?

Tags: git

Which command lists all the local branches that diverged from the remote branches they follow (either because the local branch has new commits or the remote one)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784396/git-log-graph-display-how-two-branches-are-diverging/26784458 for better answers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something simple in shell, such as:

```
for b in $(git branch -l | sed -re 's/^[ *]+//g'); do echo $b:; git diff origin/$b..$b --stat ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `git fetch` to get the files from your remote (without merging), then use

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

and you should be able to see the most recent commits of all the various branches.

Comment: Thanks, but this shows the whole (long) history and leaves it to me to figure out which branch has new commits. I'd really like to only get the branches name.

Comment: Ignore my (now deleted) last comment. Just use 

'git remote -v update'

This will show you which tracked branches are not up to date.

Comment: That command tells me that master is "[up to date]", even though it is five commits behind origin/master. :-(